# PetaPoco Paged query generation improvement

Tags: c#, sql, petapoco

I am big fan of PetaPoco and simply amazed when I see the code that is written in it. However, while using it for real life project I faced an issue wherein I had a query that was something like this:

```
SELECT  em.SysEmailID, 
        [DisplayID], 
         Case When em.SysEmailCategoryID IS NULL Then em.CategoryName Else cat.CategoryName End as 'ResultCategoryName',
         [Name], 
         IsActive, 
         em.ModifiedDateTime, 
         us.Username  
            FROM [dbo].[SysEmail] em 
                Left JOIN dbo.Users us ON em.CreatedBy = us.UserID  
                    Left JOIN dbo.SysEmailCategory cat on em.SysEmailCategoryID = cat.SysEmailCategoryID
```

ResultCategoryName is generated on the "fly" with `Case When` statements. This is a fairly simple query. Now if you ever noticed the code written in PetaPoco, you will see that it wraps up your statement and also appends Row number function. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ResultCategoryName desc) peta_rn,
         em.SysEmailID, 
         [DisplayID], 
         Case When em.SysEmailCategoryID IS NULL Then em.CategoryName Else cat.CategoryName End as 
         'ResultCategoryName',
         [Name], 
         IsActive, 
         em.ModifiedDateTime, 
         us.Username  
            FROM [dbo].[SysEmail] em Left JOIN dbo.Users us ON em.CreatedBy = us.UserID  
                Left JOIN dbo.SysEmailCategory cat on em.SysEmailCategoryID = cat.SysEmailCategoryID 

     ) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>0 AND peta_rn<=10
```

And when that happens you get Sql error `Invalid column name`"ResultCategoryName". I modified the method `'BuildPageQueries<T>'` and within `if (_dbType == DBType.SqlServer || _dbType == DBType.Oracle)` where the actual SQL is generated, I modified it to be something like:

```
 sqlPage = string.Format("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ({0}) peta_rn, peta_query.* From (Select {1}) as peta_query) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>@{2} AND peta_rn<=@{3}",
                                        sqlOrderBy == null ? "ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)" : sqlOrderBy, sqlSelectRemoved, args.Length, args.Length + 1);
```

and this generated the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ResultCategoryName asc) peta_rn, 
    peta_query.* 
        From (
                Select em.SysEmailID, [DisplayID], 
                Case When em.SysEmailCategoryID IS NULL Then em.CategoryName Else cat.CategoryName End as 'ResultCategoryName',
                [Name], 
                IsActive, 
                em.ModifiedDateTime, 
                us.Username  
                    FROM [dbo].[SysEmail] em Left JOIN dbo.Users us ON em.CreatedBy = us.UserID  
                        Left JOIN dbo.SysEmailCategory cat on em.SysEmailCategoryID = cat.SysEmailCategoryID 
                            ) as peta_query) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>0 AND peta_rn<=10
```

This works!! :). However I need to know whether this is correct way of doing so or is there any better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is wrap your sql with another select.

eg.

```
select * from (**your query here**) query order by ResultCategoryName asc
```

You only need to do this when you have calculated columns.

Comment: Oh OK. I have modified my PetaPoco source itself so I don't need to do this everytime. I guess the performance won't be hurt even if it does every time with an extra Select * from. It might be hardly 1% or may be even 0% in query analyzer.

Comment: I will have a look at this for the next major version. There are a few scenarios this will need to support. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Schotime. I created a issue for it on github too.. Btw, when is the next major release?